# How can click list view Navigate detail when I click the button in PageView?

Tags: flutter

1-There is a list view builder with title and image.
2-There is a pageview.
3-There are button previous and next.
I want to create a list view builder that has 10 items when I click item1 navigate to page view it shows item1 on page view and when I click button next it shows item2 order list view builder.
Thanks for your help.

This my code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please dont post code as image, i think the problem is because you not pass data to detail page

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the functionality your app needs using available data [(animal data)](https://zoo-animal-api.herokuapp.com/) . The data is a list of 10 animals, each having a name and an image.

Here is a [gif](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/16275252/167843897-60714f0c-f21e-4d07-aa69-9660a560e8c6.gif) to demonstrate

1. ScreenA has a list of items. ScreenB has the same list of items but as pages (i.e. PageView widget)
2. When one of the items from the list on ScreenA is tapped, the user navigates to ScreenB which is a horizontal PageView.
3. The catch => ScreenB needs to know which list item was tapped so it can show data starting at the tapped list item

I used BlocProvider to pass myBloc from ScreenA to ScreenB. The index of the tapped list item also needs to be communicated to ScreenB and that is passed via MaterialPageRoute as arguments

The code is posted to Github ([here](https://github.com/vipinkashyap/flutter_list_and_page_app))

Comment: Vipin Kumar Kashyap ,This is used with the API, it's a bit difficult for me just start flutter. I want to use only local. But thanks for your show.

Comment: Hi John, can you share your local data in the question itself?

Comment: final List<Map> _allListItems = [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Apple",
      "name": "Apple",
      "image": "assets/apple.png",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "banana",
      "name": "banana",
      "image": "assets/banana.png",
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "title": "orange",
      "name": "orange",
      "image": "assets/orange.png",
    },
  
  ];

Comment: Vipin Kumar Kashyap Can show me as local?

Comment: Sure John I’ll get back with an updated answer soon using the data you provided

Comment: Vipin Kumar Kashyap, Thanks.